CSS selector for an inline style property
Is it possible for CSS to select an element based on an inline style property the element has?
For example, if I have this HTML:
<div style="color: red;"></div>

would there be a selector like, say, this:
div[style="colour: red"]


Even if yes, inline styles have the strongest selectivity, so you would not be able to override this style.

Thanks. I don't want to override an existing property. At any rate, I've just discovered that the question has already been answered link

You can also override inline styles if you really want, with !important: [style*="color: red"] { color: blue !important; }

No, CSS cannot select elements based on inline styles or specific style properties directly. CSS selectors are limited to selecting elements based on attributes, classes, IDs, and pseudo-classes, but not on the content of the style attribute.

Did you actually check the question marked as dupe? demo

Where did you find a reference saying that the value of every attribute can be tested except the style attribute? style is an attribute.
